# In Oracle 18c+, Is it possible to use Table Flashback with a reference partitioned table?

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning, flashback

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/FLASHBACK-TABLE.html#GUID-FA9AF2FD-2DAD-4387-9E62-14AFC26EA85C), it's not very clear to me whether flashback is supported for reference partitioned tables:

> Restrictions on Flashing Back Tables
>
> This statement is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - Flashback Table operations are not valid for the following type
>   objects: tables that are part of a cluster, materialized views,
>   Advanced Queuing (AQ) tables, static data dictionary tables, system
>   tables, remote tables, object tables, nested tables, or individual
>   table partitions or subpartitions.
> - The following DDL operations change the structure of a table, so that
>   you cannot subsequently use the TO SCN or TO TIMESTAMP clause to flash
>   the table back to a time preceding the operation: upgrading, moving,
>   or truncating a table; adding a constraint to a table, adding a table
>   to a cluster; modifying or dropping a column; changing a column
>   encryption key; adding, dropping, merging, splitting, coalescing, or
>   truncating a partition or subpartition (with the exception of adding a
>   range partition).

But when I test it, it rather looks bad:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PARENT
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
) PARTITION BY RANGE (ID)
(
    PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE )
);

CREATE TABLE CHILD
(
    ID        INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PARENT_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PARENT FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (ID)
) PARTITION BY REFERENCE (FK_PARENT);

ALTER TABLE CHILD
    ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

ALTER TABLE PARENT
    ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

FLASHBACK TABLE PARENT, CHILD TO RESTORE POINT BASE;
```

Fails for `CHILD` with:

```
ORA-08199 Flashback Table operation is not supported on this object.
```

So the answer seems to be an obvious "no", but then again, it's not so obvious from the documentation. Is there maybe another way I haven't considered?

Background: I would like to use Flashback to quickly reset all tables in my containerized Oracle DB during an automated system test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's unsupported; I'm working on getting the docs updated.

If you want to reset *all* tables, you can get around this using flashback database. This reverts the whole database back to the restore point.

Assuming you're using pluggable databases, connect to the root container as a `sysdba` user and run:

```
alter pluggable database <pdbname> close;
flashback pluggable database <pdbname> to restore point base;
alter pluggable database <pdbname> open resetlogs;
```

Comment: Thank you! `flashback database` wasn't an option for me because shutting down and restarting the whole DB was too expensive, however, just restarting/flashbacking the PDB is fast enough :)